# Export excel from c# - date modification

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In sql there is a record in the format:

> 2012-06-13 08:30:00.000

When I export it to Excel, it appears in this format:

> 2012-07-18T08:30:00+03:00

How can I fix it?

I use MSSQL. Here is the c# code: (I use [RKLib.ExportData component](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8411/C-class-library-for-exporting-data-to-CSV-Excel-fi))

```
int[] iColumns = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

RKLib.ExportData.Export objExport = new RKLib.ExportData.Export("Web");

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
Response.Charset = "windows-1254";

objExport.ExportDetails(dt, iColumns, RKLib.ExportData.Export.ExportFormat.Excel, "exceldocument.xls");
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? How are you exporting it?

Comment: If you show some code, it might be easier to help you. How are you doing the export to Excel ?

Comment: Its a W3C compliant DateTime format, Can you expand on how you are doing the export ?

Comment: @StackUser, I've added a link to what I think the component you're using is, if it's wrong please do remove it.

Comment: it is right, thanx but any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related to the export. According to the documentation the first parameter there is a `DataTable`, in your case `dt`.

Wherever else in your code you are creating and populating this datatable, you should be able to sort the formatting there. Somewhere between the database and this datatable is where the extra bit is being added.

You haven't mentioned what the datatype of the column it came from, or the datatype of the column in the `DataTable` it's going into, but I'm going to assume that the source column is a `DateTime` in your database, but it ends in a string column in your datatable? If this is true, you could use string manipulation on the datatable column, or change the sql that populates it to get it in the format you would like.